# Mean filter on 2D array with Numpy, SciPy or Scikit-image

Tags: numpy, filter, scipy, mean, scikit-image

I'm looking for a 2D mean filter with 3x3 window. I tried NumPy:

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
b = np.average(a, axis=(0, 1), weights=np.ones((3, 3)))
```

but it fails with:

```
TypeError: 1D weights expected when shapes of a and weights differ.
```

Is 2D mean filter supported in NumPy? Are there options in SciPy or Scikit-image?

Comment: Take a look at [`scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter.html).

Answer (score 3):

`np.average` isn't what you want, but maybe you're looking for [scipy.signal.convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html)?

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
b = scipy.signal.convolve(a, np.ones((3,3))/9, mode='valid')
```

`mode='valid'` gets you a 3x3 array (you lose two elements on each axis if you want all of the values you average to come from the input array).

`mode='same'` gets you a 5x5 array (elements in the first/last column/row get one or more zeroes included in the average).

`mode='full'` gets you a 7x7 array (the upper left element of the output will be the average of only the upper left element of `a` with eight zeroes, etc.).

The default is `mode='full'` presumably because you could get the other ones just by trimming some elements off of it.